# How to make a list of tuples in Java

Tags: java, python, list, tuples

In Python I have a code:

```
segments = [(0, cX, 0, cY), (cX, w, 0, cY), (cX, w, cY, h), (0, cX, cY, h)]
```

How can I make this using Java?

Comment: In Java you use either custom Objects (which is the preferred way )  or collections/arrays (if all elements are of same type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java not have tuples by default but you can use http://www.javatuples.org, I'm believing that you can find other implementations too.

if want to make it 2 dimensions array assuming all values are int this is correct syntax

```
int[][] segments = new int[][] { { 0, 1, 0, 1 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (which is much more verbose than in Python) is to write a new class called Segment with x1, y1, x2, y2 as fields, with corresponding getters and setters.

You could also define 2 classes : Segment and Point. Segment would have 2 fields : point1 and point2, Point would have x and y as fields.

segments would then be a Collection (e.g. Set or List) of Segments.